# Access the admin panel for an embedded RavenDB in ASP.NET MVC running on IIS Express

Tags: asp.net-mvc, ravendb

I'm building a ASP.NET MVC site. I want to use RavenDb (www.ravendb.net) - the embedded version.

My problem is that I also want to be able to access the "RavenDb admin" tool so look in the database, test queries etc.

Normally when you have RavenDb running in "Server" mode you can access this "RavenDb admin" via: localhost:8080

As stated, I want my database to run embedded, so it runs as a part of my ASP.NET MVC site and therefore lives inside the IIS Express that hosts my ASP.NET MVC.

I have found this: http://ravendb.net/faq/embedded-with-http

It tells me to initialize my datastore with the property UseEmbeddedHttpServer = true.

```
var documentStore = new EmbeddableDocumentStore
{
    DataDirectory = "Data",
    UseEmbeddedHttpServer = true
};
```

I've done that, but how to I then access the "RavenDb admin" part?
localhost:8080 wouldn't work, as my site is running on like localhost:49833

It might be me who is missing something, but I have done a lot of googling on this and still can't find the answer.

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Start Visual Studio 2010 as administrator - very important.
Then make sure the Raven.Studio.xap is in the root folder of your website.

Now, after you have launched the site in ISS Express you can access the admin part of RavenDB via http://localhost:8080/

It's important that you actually "start" the website, by loading a page on it or similar, so the Application_Start method os called - else RavenDB will not be started.

Comment: As of version 2.0 the xap is embedded in the raven binary and putting it in root folder of your site is not necessary

Answer (score 1):

You can certainly access RavenDB at localhost:8080 - it runs its own http server (with its own port) that has nothing to do with IIS. So, it basically doesn't matter if you're hosting RavenDB inside a console application, windows service or IIS.

Just copy the file Raven.Studio.xap (you can find it in the /Server directory from a release version) into your root folder (the place where Global.asax is) and you'll be fine.

Comment: I had actually tried that, but now that you confirmed that this were actually the right direction I tried a little more. I found out (stupid me) that I forgot to call Initialize() on the DocumentStore..so it never started :P

Comment: After I did this it seemed to start and the my firewall popped up asking if I were ok with it. I told it yes and the I got: System.Net.HttpListenerException: Access is denied
So that's what I'm investigation right now. :) Thanks Daniel so far. :)

Comment: Ok I found these two: http://groups.google.com/group/ravendb/browse_thread/thread/0fe902e5d0f0343a
and
http://groups.google.com/group/ravendb/browse_thread/thread/4155d8de1c01c378

I still can't make it work, but it came to my mind that I actually don't HAVE to be able to access RavenDb on the server. It's ok for me to just download the RavenDb data folder and the start up a server local and inspect data that way.

Comment: Mads, you need to give the IIS worker process admin rights, so that it can open up a port on localhost. Unfortunately, there's no way to get around this: http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/93940/httplistener-requires-admin-priveleges

Comment: Just needed to run VS2010 as administrator and copy the .xap file to the root folder - now it's working as it should :)

Comment: Great, that sounds good. You could please answer your own question then and accept the answer, so that others know what to do when they find there way here.

Comment: Ok cool, I will just do that. I'm not so use to post here on Stackoverflow, normally I just read and find answers :)

Comment: As of Version 2.0, Raven.Studio.xap is an embedded resource in Raven.Database.dll, so you will no longer need to copy it.

Answer (score 1):

I got hung up on this.  I could see that port 8080 was bound and listening, but I kept getting 404 errors back.  Turns out you need to include any virtual directory portion of your web application's URL when referring to the Raven Studio.

If your application is registered with IIS as:
`http://localhost/MyAwesomeApp`

You would access Raven Studio at:
`http://localhost:8080/MyAwesomeApp`

Hope this helps someone!